# How to prevent the soft keyboard from popping up while using a physical keyboard in Android app? kotlin or java

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I want to prevent the soft keyboard from popping up while using a physical keyboard in Android app.

I have tried inputmanager

```
val inputMethodManager: InputMethodManager = context?.getSystemService(
                    AppCompatActivity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE
                ) as InputMethodManager
                inputMethodManager.showInputMethodPicker()
```

and also used this

```
editText.showSoftInputOnFocus = false
```

but the soft keyboard still popups when I start typing on the physical keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

**MainActivity.java**

> This Code Hide Soft Keyboard in your Project

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
       getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
    }
  }
```

Comment: What if he disconnects physical keyboard? will softkeyboard automatically pops up?